# Replacing Large metal registers (HVAC) with wood registers will result in decreased air flow -can I compensate with an intake booster fan?

Tags: hvac, register, intake-fan

This is for a small bungalow and the main floor currently works on one large intake register (29.5x5.5 opening). This is made of metal and it was sitting on top of the old floor. Since I replaced the floor I am now trying to replace this register with a better looking one that would be flush with the floor. Because this new one will be made of wood I will to build it with wider grates and that will decrease the airflow.
Is it OK/doable to use register booster fans installed under this register in order to improve the efficiency ? (it will probably have to be a smart register that would have to work in sync with the  furnace)

Comment: No that is not the case. However a reduced airflow means a less efficient furnace

Comment: I'm no HVAC guy, but some maths tells me that 29.5"x5.5" is 162.25 square inches. If the old metal grate blocked 10% of that, you have 146.025 sq in for air flow. If your new wood grate blocks 20% of that you will have 129.8 sq in for air flow. You'll need to increase the size of the vent opening to get back to the original amount of air flow.

Comment: Yep - just make it bigger - wider, longer, or both.

Comment: that is not possible. The current thickness of the grate is 1/16 in metal. You can't do better than that in wood. I tried changing the geometry of the grate (it is a grid currently and I tried to run veticals only or horizontals only and that did not change the result)

Comment: that would be a debate for another thread, lets stick to the topic

Comment: It's pretty rare for home ducting to flow enough to begin with. You can try adding a booster but it's likely to be noisy. What's the foot/min measurement on the current register?

Comment: 490/500ft/min measured with this guy https://i.imgur.com/5biQby9.png

Comment: Can you share details about the wooden grate design/construction? Depending on details, you could possibly get pretty close to the original grate's airflow.

Comment: Feel free to suggest any design you want. I tried all the possible combinations for horizontal or vertical grates and I simulated this using excel and simple maths and tried all the possible geometries. The current register has 130sqin of open areas. The rest is covered by a metal grid, grates are 1/16 thick

Comment: Here is a link to my simulation https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WhzQahvDuktXa2GvvnZbp849t1XAxkF48N4GREI7OQA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you're at 500fpm now I expect you're going to stay at 700 or below when you reduce the area. You might not take much of an efficiency hit, just add a bit of noise.

Comment: Is there anything that I can read to understand the scientific basis of your conclusion? My understanding is that the furnace/airflow will not be balanced and the blower will work harder That will shoren the life of the motor and this is the only intake for the entire floor (~1000sqft)so  it definitely matters

Comment: run the fan harder and tighten the vents to rebalance.

Comment: Like I can, Is there a way to control how fast the fan goes for a furnace (assuming fan = blower)